# How to print part of a line

Tags: regex, text, printing, groovy

I searched a text file for all lines containing the word `velcro`.  I now want to print the contents of those lines, but only the parts that follow `velcro`

say I have a line of text

`the purple monkey climbs the velcro cactus`

How would I print everything that comes after `velcro` (looking for general answer)

I started out with:

```
c = /.*velcro.*/

if (line ==~ c){
println ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a capturing group in your regular expression:

```
c = ~/.*velcro(.*)/

m = line =~ c
if (m) {
    println m[0][1]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works just fine!  Could you explain what is going on here?  I'm mainly interested in the line `println m[0][1]`, but if you care to not the other stuff too that would be great

Comment: The `[0]` returns matches from the first (and only) occurance of the regex in the string.  `[0][0]` would be the entire string that was matched.  `[0][1]` is the first capture group.  There's more information in the User Guide: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Regular+Expressions

Comment: is the capturing group `(.*)` ?

Comment: Yes, everything in the parentheses gets captured.